# Parameterised queries in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, parameter-passing

I need a clarification, i went through different turorials on entity framework and implemented in my project.

Later when it came to security of application, i understood that parameterised queries are good for security.

My questions are :

1. Will entity framwork automatically take care of parameterised  queries
2. If yes, where it is implemented?
3. Is it implemeneted in context class like below?

---

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TriggerEvent>().HasKey(c => c.TriggerEventId)
            .HasIndex("IX_TriggerEvent_LegacyName", IndexOptions.Unique,
                        e => e.Property(x => x.LegacyName))
            .Map(m =>
            {
                  m.MapInheritedProperties();
                  m.ToTable("refTriggerEvent", schemaName: "CaseManagement");
            });
```

Comment: erm... Linq to Entities doesn't use parameterised queries... Entity SQL can... Query builder method can (using ObjectQuery)... executing raw SQL is the real issue of parameters being dangerous... EF will perform datatype matching to a greater extent (not sure exactly where it does it though).. your code defines part of your model... it is not a parameterised query.

Comment: This may prove interesting to you... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Will entity framwork automatically take care of parameterised queries

Yes.

> If yes, where it is implemented?

EF is open source, you could trawl through the implementation.

> Is it implemeneted in context class like below?

That code is defining (part of) the model. There is no query to parametrise.

If you configure logging (`DbConext.Database.Log` property) you can see the SQL and parameters being passed to the database.